# Assert is not working in PHP. So simple. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, assert

It's like assert isn't even being called. I am confused.

#### The version

```
php -v

PHP 7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

The script:

#### *x.php*

```
<?php
    print ("Hello\n");

    assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE,true);
    assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL,true);

    assert(false);
    assert(true);

    print ("Bye\n");
```

when I run it

```
php x.php

Hello
Bye
```

I would have expected the program to terminate with an exception. Am I going crazy?

Comment: In PHP7.0.12 I get a `Warning: assert(): assert(false) failed`

Comment: Assert changed a bit in PHP7 check [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php)

Comment: I upgraded to 7.0.12 but the output is the same.

`code`php -v
PHP 7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
:~/code/x/test$ php x.php
Hello
Bye

Comment: Then check the parameter (all mentioned in the manual) you have set in your `php.ini`

Answer (score 26):

It looks like assertions are OFF out of the box on 7.0. In my *php.ini* file *zend.assertions* was set to -1, which means they are ignored. I have changed the setting to 1.

```
[Assertion]
; Switch whether to compile assertions at all (to have no overhead at run-time)
; -1: Do not compile at all
;  0: Jump over assertion at run-time
;  1: Execute assertions
; Changing from or to a negative value is only possible in php.ini! (For turning assertions on and off at run-time, see assert.active, when zend.assertions = 1)
; Default Value: 1
; Development Value: 1
; Production Value: -1
; http://php.net/zend.assertions
zend.assertions = 1
```

The script now works as expected.

```
php x.php

Hello
PHP Warning:  assert(): assert(false) failed in /home/ubuntu/code/x/test/x.php on line 8
```

Comment: Include  `assert.exception` to `1` if need to see an exception (Introduced in php 7).