# How to display assert errors in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, assert, assertion

I'd like my Laravel app to output assert errors in the browser during development. Although I have put some asserts in my Laravel code that should definitely fail, I never see any errors outputted in the browser?

Is there a assert reporting configuration in Laravel that can force these errors to display?

In production, I would like the assert failures to call a callback method and email me the error.

Comment: this [`assert()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php)? are you sure that `php.ini` already configured?

Comment: are you using asserts in testing env?

Comment: @BagusTesa - yes, assert()

Comment: @FatemehMajd - not in a testing environment.

Comment: why would you use assert in a non-testing environment? asserts, of course, do not work in non-testing env. there are surely other ways to do assert something without actually using an assert function. what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: asserts work fine in a non-testing environment. For example, I can get it to display assert errors on my localhost when doing plain PHP. I tend to assert a lot of my assumptions while developing code -- and when one of my assumptions is incorrect, I want to be warned.

Comment: I wrote up an answer but then came across [what is probably a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129963/assert-not-working-in-php-so-simple-what-am-i-doing-wrong)?  In short: check [`zend.assertions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.assertions).

Comment: Debugging output sometimes doesn't make it to the browser, particularly in things like Ajax calls. What I generally like to do is append debugging output to a log file which I can inspect at some time after a run. It also has the advantage that you can leave the assertions in the Production code, as it won't interrupt the end-user, but the debugging log file remains available to maintenance developers.

Answer (score 5):

[`zend.assertions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.assertions) are likely in production mode. In other words, assertions are disabled and ignored.

> When set to -1, assertion code will not be generated, making the assertions zero-cost. <sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.assertions)</sup>

You can view this configuration setting from the command line:

```sh
$ php -i | grep 'zend.assertions' # zend.assertions => -1 => -1
```

If you are using homestead, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275579/configure-the-php-ini-on-vagrant-homestead) post to change the configuration.